# Recover lost partitions ( or partition table) after fdisk in debian

Tags: debian-squeeze, fdisk

I am running Debian Squeeze in my laptop. I did a big mistake. Instead of doing `fdisk /dev/sdb` (which is my usb pendrive), I fdisk-ed `/dev/sda`, which is my primary hdd.
When prompted, I chose options `o` and `w` and the reboot my machine.

Now, I cannot start my machine as it says no OS found.

Is it that, all my data is lost or only the partition table? How do we recover the data?

Edit:-
Initially I had 5 partitions. The partitions are as follows:-
A 105 GB for Windows installation, a 170 GB for storing data (possible NTFS), another 170 GB (possibly NTFS), a 1 GB (swap space) and 20 GB (ext4 partition). I was having a debian squeeze and win 7 dual boot.

105 GB
170 GB
170 GB
1 GB
20 GB

After loading an Ubuntu live cd, when I tried to see whether any partition structure exist using the Gpart command like,

```
sudo gpart /dev/sda
```

I got the following output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gpart /dev/sda

Begin scan...
Possible partition(Windows NT/W2K FS), size(107419mb), offset(59139mb)
Possible partition(DOS FAT), size(2mb), offset(187738mb)
End scan.

Checking partitions...
Partition(OS/2 HPFS, NTFS, QNX or Advanced UNIX): primary 
Partition(Primary DOS with 12 bit FAT): primary 
Ok.

Guessed primary partition table:
Primary partition(1)
   type: 007(0x07)(OS/2 HPFS, NTFS, QNX or Advanced UNIX)
   size: 107419mb #s(219996159) s(121117248-341113406)
   chs:  (1023/254/63)-(1023/254/63)d (7539/51/1)-(21233/83/33)r

Primary partition(2)
   type: 001(0x01)(Primary DOS with 12 bit FAT)
   size: 2mb #s(4544) s(384488496-384493039)
   chs:  (1023/254/63)-(1023/254/63)d (23933/77/1)-(23933/149/8)r

Primary partition(3)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(4)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r
```

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

The screenshot is at 
[image]

Shall I continue to write to the disk ? Does the partitions shown match my previous partitions as I mentioned ?

Comment: As per the [faq](http://serverfault.com/faq), this site is not about anything in a home setting

Comment: Time to pull out your backups

Comment: @MarkHenderson inb4 "backups? what backups?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot from a Live CD and try using [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) or [gpart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gpart) utilities, which can in many cases find lost partitions automatically. One popular Live CD distribution suited for such recovery tasks is [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/).

Comment: Please see the edits in my question.

Comment: Try `sudo gpart -k 2048 -n 2048 /dev/sda` — Microsoft operating systems since Windows Vista and recent Linux distributions usually align partitions to 1 MiB boundaries, which does not match the default `gpart` assumptions. If `gpart` still does not find your partitions, you can also try `sudo gpart -k 1 -n s /dev/sda`, but this can take a very long time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestio. Can you look at the scrrenshot and the partitions I specified. Does that match ?

Comment: Also,  I am using Ubuntu 10.10 live cd.

Comment: Your partition definitely were not found correctly — try adding `-k 2048 -n 2048` as suggested. Using Ubuntu 10.10 might be OK — gpart is not updated very often.

Comment: That worked man, both of the commands you specified shows the partitions and their size correctly... Now the question is how do we restore that partition table ?

Is it using 
sudo gpart -W /dev/sda /dev/sda

Comment: So you see all of your partitions with these `gpart` options? Then, if you are really sure that the result looks fine, you can add `-W /dev/sda` to the command line which gives a good result (be sure to keep all other options, otherwise you will get the same wrong result as on your first try).

Comment: So, should I write `sudo gkpart -k 1 -n s -W /dev/sda` ?

Comment: `sudo gpart -k 1 -n s -W /dev/sda /dev/sda` (first `/dev/sda` is the device for writing, second is the device for reading).

Comment: When i run that command, it first asked whether to edit that table. I chose no, then it asked me which partition to activate (1-4). I don't know what to do here ?

How long will it take to complete, as,the laptop is low in battery.

Comment: If you see a small NTFS partition (usually about 100 MB), activate it (it should be the Windows 7 system partition which contains its boot manager), otherwise activate the first NTFS partition. Linux bootloader was most likely installed into the MBR and would need repairing anyway. The write operation should be almost instant (only search takes a long time).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8845/discussion-between-roshan-george-and-sergey-vlasov)

Comment: That worked super fine. Every partitions except swap space and Debian installation partition is not available. When inside windows, it shows unallocated space, but can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

If the old table is recoverable testdisk should find it.  If not - you may be able to get the data by using testdisk's data recovery option or try dd or ddrecscue to get a copy of the hard-drive on disk (assuming you create a scenario where you have a free hard-drive to rescue the data to).  If you can get the data you can re-create the partiontion table and then put your data back on.  The good news is that most-likely your data is still on that drive.

Comment: I tried using test-disk, but i'm unsure how to use it.